# Closing JDBC connection when calling a database multiple times inside the same function

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, transactions

I am trying to execute multiple queries in a single function using single connection object. I would like to know what is the best practice to close the database connection in a scenario like this. Currently , I close the connection once all the db calls are completed. I am wondering whether I need to close the connection and open a new connection for every db call. Which is better?

Comment: Why would you feel the need to create/close a new connection for every call to the database? It makes more sense to use what @Sean is suggesting so that you are using the instance per transaction which can contain multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the `Connection` open as long as possible. Creating a database connection is a (relatively) expensive operation, so you don't want to do it more often that you need to.

To manage the lifetime, you should use [the try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) assuming you are on at least Java 7:

```
try (Connection connection = myDataSource.getConnection()) {
    // Do your queries here
}
```

Comment: However, wouldn't it be using a connection that could be used for other db call.

Comment: I don't follow. If you are going to run multiple queries in a row you should not release the `Connection` between them.

Comment: I don't entirely agree, a (logical) connection should be closed as soon as possible (ie: when a unit of work is completed); the expense of creating the physical connection should be compensated by using a connection pool.